# How to make UISegmentedControl act like a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I use UISegmentedControl to load different subviews when different segments are selected? Im new to objective-c and iOS programming.

OR is there a way to make UITabBarController look like a UISegmentedControl?

Answer (score 3):

For a programatic approach

in loadView:

```
{
    NSArray *segments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Left", @"Right", nil];


    segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:segments];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self
    action:@selector(changeSubViews)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    contentView = [UIView alloc]initwithFrame:(the frame where you want the subViews to be displayed)];
    [self.view addSubView:contentView];

    }

    - (void)changeSubViews
        {
            switch(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
            {
            case 0:
                {
                    [rightView removeFromSuperView];
                    if (leftView ==nil){leftView alloc, init;}
                    [contentView addSubView:leftView];
                    break;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    [leftView removeFromSuperView];
                    if (rightView ==nil){rightView alloc, init;}
                    [contentView addSubView:rightView];
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `UIToolbar` to your root controller's `view`. In it, you'd have a `UISegementedControl` with actions that the root controller handle. Depending on the segment clicked, you would load up a different view and display the view under the `UIToolbar` (and anything else that you want the view to be below).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok for this purpose you make two views in your view and make property for both in .h file
and 
Attach an IBAction to the segmented control and write code like this

```
if(self.yourSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {   
    view1.hidden=YES;
        view2.hidden=NO;
    }
    else if(self.categorySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
    {  
    view2.hidden=YES;
        view2.hidden=NO:
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I already know how to do this. But how do I show the active subview while hiding inactive subviews? just like the tabbar

Comment: why not you make two view where you use same segmented control.And you can show selection of the segment control.

Comment: that's my question. I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You should consider crafterm's answer in this post: [UISegmentedControl Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118358/uisegmentedcontrol-best-practice)

This will allow you to maintain your normal ViewController behavior (support rotation, memory warnings, etc.) while allowing for the segmented control on top of it.